# How to find xpath in a new window handle

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, window, handle

My site has a button that opens a new window handle.
I recognize the new window handle and switch to it.
when I try to inspect elements on this new handle I must press F12 and the DevTools open in a new window.
I enter my xpath and it highlights the object correctly.
when I search the object in my code it does not find it, and it seems that the HTML is not complete.
Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your code, also if possible share the url of the page

Comment: `when I search the object in my code it does not find it, and it seems that the HTML is not complete.` - Show us the code, xpath, error stack trace etc.

Comment: Check for iframe. It has happened to me lot of times.